# STXXL equivalent in Java

Tags: java, collections, large-data-volumes, stxxl

I'm searching a collection framework designed for huge datasets in Java that behaves transparently, like [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) does for C++.

It should transparently swap to disk, but in a much more efficient manner than plain OS-based VM swapping. A StringBuffer/String drop-in replacement would be a big plus.

Comment: what do you mean by huge data sets? One man's huge is another man's trickle.

Comment: More than what fits in RAM :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These fill needs only partially:

Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition database backed collections:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/berkeley-db/je/java/index.html

Joafip persistent collections:
http://joafip.sourceforge.net/javadoc/net/sf/joafip/java/util/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

[Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/What+Is+Terracotta)